# CSS loading spinner not working from style.css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have been banging my head on this for a while and Im sure the answer is very simple, but you know how coding goes.

I am trying to run a css loading spinner from my style.css file.
So I have placed this at the top of the modal Im wanting to use the spinner in...

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/content/templates/dashboard/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/content/templates/dashboard/css/style-mobile.css" />
```

I then have the div's laid out

```
<div class="cssloader-overlay"> 
        <div class="cssloader-container">
            <div class="cssload-whirlpool"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is a snippet from the style sheet

```
.cssloader-container {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display:none;
}

.cssloader-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:none;
}

.cssload-whirlpool,
.cssload-whirlpool::before,
.cssload-whirlpool::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    border-left-color: rgb(230,0,0);
    border-radius: 974px;
        -o-border-radius: 974px;
        -ms-border-radius: 974px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 974px;
        -moz-border-radius: 974px;
}
```

Currently my spinner only works if I place the css in a style element in my actual modal. When I try to run it from the style.css file, it does not work. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Place this inside your `<head>` as you had before.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/templates/dashboard/css/style.css">
```

I don't know if you've tried this, but it sounds like this is the problem/solution.

Comment: I have tried all variations of this, the way I have it above is the only way to get the path correct. This does still not work... I know Im missing something simple but not sure what.